# Join two columns from dataframeA with column from dataframeB

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, join

**dataframeA:**

```
|ID_ENTITE|ID_ENTITE_GARANTE|
|A        |B                |
|D        |A                |
```

**dataframeB:**

```
|ID_ENTITE|ID_ENTITE_SOURCE|
|X        |A               |
|Y        |B               |
|Z        |D               |
```

I want to have an updated dataframeA containing:

```
|ID_ENTITE|ID_ENTITE_GARANTE|New1|New2|
|A        |B                |X   |Y   |
|D        |A                |Z   |X   |
```

I should left join both columns from dataframeA with column **ID_ENTITE_SOURCE** from dataframeB. How can I do that in one instruction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `join` it multiple times with 2 `columns`

also need some rename of column, because its confusing

Here is full example of it

```
val dfA = Seq(
  ("A", "B"),
  ("D", "A")
).toDF("ID_ENTITE", "ID_ENTITE_GARANTE")

val dfB = Seq(
  ("X", "A"),
  ("Y", "B"),
  ("Z", "D")
).toDF("ID_ENTITE", "ID_ENTITE_SOURCE")
  .withColumn("New", $"ID_ENTITE")
  .drop("ID_ENTITE")
```

//Rename column

```
dfA.join(dfB, dfA("ID_ENTITE") === dfB("ID_ENTITE_SOURCE")) // first join 
  .withColumnRenamed("new", "New1")
  .drop("ID_ENTITE_SOURCE")
  .join(dfB, dfA("ID_ENTITE_GARANTE") === dfB("ID_ENTITE_SOURCE")) // second join 
  .drop("ID_ENTITE_SOURCE")
  .withColumnRenamed("new", "new2")

  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---------+-----------------+----+----+
|ID_ENTITE|ID_ENTITE_GARANTE|New1|new2|
+---------+-----------------+----+----+
|A        |B                |X   |Y   |
|D        |A                |Z   |X   |
+---------+-----------------+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this using sql - I named the two dataframes as "dfa" and "dfb":

```
spark.sql("select *, (select first(dfb.ID_ENTITE) from dfb where dfb.ID_ENTITE_SOURCE = dfa.ID_ENTITE) as new1, (select first(dfb.ID_ENTITE) from dfb where dfb.ID_ENTITE_SOURCE = dfa.ID_ENTITE_GARANTE) as new2 from dfa")
```

Output:

```
   +---------+-----------------+----+----+
   |ID_ENTITE|ID_ENTITE_GARANTE|new1|new2|
   +---------+-----------------+----+----+
   |        A|                B|   X|   Y|
   |        D|                A|   Z|   X|
   +---------+-----------------+----+----+
```

You can also write this using joins. I just wrote a simple solution.